# My custom launchers are highlighted in Docky when Chrome is launched

Tags: launcher, google-chrome, icons, docky

I've had this problem for a while, but for some reason it just irritated me more than usual today.

I have Google Chrome pinned to Docky, as well as several custom launchers for various programs not installed via the repositories.
However, when I launch Chrome, its icon is not highlighted; instead, several (but not all, which is weird) of my custom launcher icons pinned to Docky are highlighted and behave as though they were Chrome, i.e. I click on them and it takes me to the active Chrome window, and right clicking them only brings up Chrome options. Additionally, clicking on the Chrome icon again opens a new window.

Here is a picture of Docky when Nautilus and Chrome (from which I am typing this) are the only programs currently running:[image]

From the picture, the three icons highlighted are Nautilus, the custom launcher that looks like Mars, and the custom launcher directly to the left of the trash icon. There are six other custom icons pinned that aren't highlighted, and, of course, Chrome is not highlighted.

When Chrome is not running, these custom launchers launch their intended programs, are highlighted, and behave as they should.
From my research on Ask Ubuntu, I noticed there seem to be a lot of issues with Chrome and Docky, but I haven't found a reference to my particular issue. Has anyone else experienced this or have a potential fix? I've tried reinstalling both Docky and Chrome on several occasions which doesn't seem to help...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Some icon conflicts can be resolved by dragging the icons for the programs you need from the /usr/share/applications directory into Docky. Using your file manager, navigate to this folder and give this a try.